# android listview after image is updated still use one it has in cache

Tags: android, listview

In my listview i have image and text which can be updated from internet. Images is saved on external memory. When update is happening text is showed correct but image is still old one, the one which is in cache. On update i delete old image and create new one with same name. But unless im clearing app cache, listview will show old image. How could i solve this ?
I also tried to clear cache programmatically but thats causing some other problems.

On postExecute i try call `MyListView.getMdataAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`however it doesnt help.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = convertView;

    final ViewHolder holder;
    Items2 i = items.get(position);
    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        holder.text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvRestList);
        holder.image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgList);

        view.setTag(holder);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    holder.pos = position;
    Items2 item = (Items2)i;
    holder.text.setText(item.name);

    imageLoader.displayImage("file:///"+context.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()+File.separator+String.valueOf(position)+".jpg", holder.image, options);

    return view;
}
```

ImageLoader is Universal Image Loader.

Comment: Can you please show the adapter code?

Comment: Found why that was happening, by default imageloader was caching images in memory so on update had to clear memory cache of imageloader